# Difference between two rows for a column field

Tags: db2

I have table TestTable

```
ID Name   value
-- ------ -----
1  SOUMYA 10
1  SOUMYA 8
```

I want to write a query in DB2 which will return.

```
ID Name   Oldvalue NewValue Difference
--------------------------------------
1  SOUMYA    10       8        2
```

Comment: welcome to SO,what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you know which value is new and which one is old?

Comment: If I tell you in details, this is a result of a single table with search clause. for example, Select ID, Name, value from Table 1 where Unique_Id = '1A'. Now I want to get the difference of these values. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to retrieve the old value? where is it stored?

In DB2 there is a feature called Time Travel, that includes the old values. This is specific for db2 since version 10.1. There are different ways to write that queries using Time Travel.

Please check this video for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JrQdzdYwOA

You can also create a trigger in the value to log the old and new values in another table, and they just query the other table. However, the time problem arrives here, and that is the reason Time Travel exists.

Comment: This assumes, of course, his version of DB2 is LUW (and a recent enough edition), and that the table was created to take advantage of this feature (and potentially that `UPDATE` was called with the proper additional keywords - the cursory look I took was a little ambiguous on this point).  I've been curious about this capability for a while, though...

Comment: If I tell you in details, this is a result of a single table with search clause. for example,                                        Select ID, Name, value from Table 1 where Unique_Id = '1A'.        Now I want to get the difference of these values. Please advise.